# How to: prefetchable related name with implicit filter

Tags: django, django-models

It is understood that foreign keys can have `related_name`s, like this:

```
class Foo(Model):
    ...

class Bar(Model):
    foo = ForeignKey(Foo, related_name='bars')
    hidden = BooleanField()
```

The effect is `foo = Foo.objects.first(); foo.bars.all()` yields any `Bar`s attached to that `Foo`.

However, I want to add a default filter to all `.bars.all()`, such that `Bar`s that are marked as "hidden" are never part of the resulting queryset.

It is tempting to do:

```
class Foo(Model):
    ...
    @property
    def shown_bars(self):
        return self.bars.filter(hidden=False)
```

and just use `foo.shown_bars` instead of `foo.bars`, but my objective is to make such a `related_name` nested-prefetchable as well, i.e.

```
class Baz(Model):
    foo = ForeignKey(Foo)

# The bars in this queryset *also* automatically excludes bars that are hidden.
# Using `shown_bars` here undoes the prefetch.
Baz.objects.prefetch_related('foo__bars')
```

So `nested_bars` cannot be used directly in such expressions.

Is there a way to achieve this in Django 1.11 or 2.x?

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way to exert control over the queryset retrieved in a `prefetch_related` operation is to use [`Prefetch`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects) objects introduced in [Django 1.7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/1.7/#new-prefetch-object-for-advanced-prefetch-related-operations).

You define the desired queryset:

```
filtered_bars = Bar.objects.filter(wanted=True)
```

Alternatively, if you have defined a [custom manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/managers/#s-custom-managers) `filtered` on `Bar`:

```
filtered_bars = Bar.filtered.all()
```

Then you use the queryset in the `select_related` call:

```
Baz.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch(
    'bars',
    queryset=filtered_bars))
```

Another alternative one might think of is to manipulate the base manager of the related object (here `Bar`) which would automatically affect default prefetch operations. However, the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/managers/#s-don-t-filter-away-any-results-in-this-type-of-manager-subclass) explicitly caution against doing this as it would prevent Django from accessing all objects, something it needs to be able to do.